# jQuery tablesorter "unsortable column" problem

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a set of records in a list with initial number on the left column, like this: 
No-Name-Age
1. Jack 50
2. Bill 35
3. Wayne 30
4. Mike 15

This is my code.

```
$("#datatable").tablesorter({
    headers:{0: {sorter: false}},
    widgets: ['zebra']
});
```

I can make the headers unclickable, but what I want is to make the initial number **unsortable**, so when user sorts by age, they would be like this:
1. Mike 15
2. Wayne 30
3. Bill 35
4. Jack 50

How is it possible? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about making the first column unsortable, just rewrite the values every time the table is sorted:

```
$('table').tablesorter(/* Your favorite options */);
$('table').bind('sortend', function() {
    $(this).find('tbody tr td:first-child').each(function(i) {
        $(this).html((i + 1) + '.');
    });
});
```

The index numbers in the first column aren't real data anywhere, they're generated so generating them every time not only solves your problem but makes sense too.